# How can I have both res/values-pt_PT and res/values-pt_BR on Android?

Tags: android, internationalization, android-resources

I keep getting an error when creating folders for internationalization. But the errors appear just for folders with the name like values-xx_XX. If I have values-xx everything is ok, but like I asked in the title I want to make 2 separate folders for the (aprox.)the same language: values-pt_PT,values-pt_BR. How can I do that without getting any errors? Note: The error is not specified anywhere, the eclipse is just marking the folder with a red cross and doesn't allow me to run the project.

Every hint is appreciated. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the format `values-xx-rXX` instead of `values-xx_XX`. In this instance you should use `values-pt-rPT` and `values-pt-rBR`.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

> The language is defined by a two-letter ISO 639-1 language code,
>   optionally followed by a two letter ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 region code
>   (preceded by lowercase "r").

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Indeed the documentation specifies this problem, next time I should search/look with more attention. But now I have another problem. What string should I give as a parameter to Locale? if for example I have the folder values-pt-rBR what should be the string? I already tried pt_BR but it doesn't work. Thx for the answer

Comment: Ok I found the solution. I used another constructor Locale("br","BR") and it works. I still don't know why it doesn't work Locale("br_BR"). Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done it myself, but after a quick search here, I found [Setting region based Local in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258563/setting-region-based-local-in-android) where they suggest using the constructor as you did:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar","SA"); //(language,country)
```

But also, if you wish to pass it as one parameter, you'd still leverage the lowercase "r" as in the "values" folder, like this:

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("ar-rSA");
```

Hope it helps :)