# Setting region based Local in android

Tags: android, localization

I want to specify different values for arabic language in different regions.

I have the following values folders in the res directory:

```
    res/values  
    res/vaues-ar
    res/values-ar-rSA
```

based on the region selected, i am trying to set the local like this:

```
      Locale locale = new Locale("ar-SA");  
      Locale.setDefault(locale);
      Configuration config = new Configuration();
      config.locale = locale;
      getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

but it always loads the values from res/values-ar folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i figured it out. To set a region based locale i needed to use a different constructor. Just changed
this line

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("ar-SA");
```

to this

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("ar","SA"); //(language,country)
```

Comment: or Locale locale = new Locale("ar-rSA");